# How to generate an equation by concatenating string recursively in java?

Tags: java, oop

Trying to implement mathematical equation generation through recursively concatenating string returned by class containing same class as child nodes. Final equation contains repeated variables and I want to figure out how to end the recursion in this scenario.

I have a class1 which contains a Set/List of the same class1 objects. Also class1 contains Set/list of class2 and class3 objects. Now traversing through the parent class, I need to generate an expression from all the child and parent objects in a hierarchical manner. For eg: Exp1(class1) contains Exp2(class1), an operator(class3) and an attribute (class2). Now have to generate a long expression through the tree of objects such as class1,class2 are on the left and right sides of the equation and operator(op) in the middle.

```
public Map<String,String> generatecode(Map<String,String> Codes) {
    String code = Codes.get("code");
    String exit = Codes.get("exit");
    String operator = "";
    String operand1 = "";
    String operand2 = "";
    Set<Class2> attrs = getAttributes();
    Set<Class1> exps = getExpressions();
    if(attrs.size()>=2)
        exit="1";
    Iterator<Class2> itr = attrs.iterator();
    while (itr.hasNext()) {
        class2 attr=itr.next();

        if(attr.getProperty("operand").equals("operand1")) {
            operand1= attr.getName();
        }
        else if(attr.getProperty("operand").equals("operand2")) {
            operand2= attr.getName();
        }
    }
    if(!exit.equals("1") & exps!=null & !exps.isEmpty()) {
            Iterator<Class1> itr = exps.iterator();
            while (itr.hasNext()) {
                Class1 exp=itr.next();
                if(exp.getProperty("operand").equals("operand1")) {
                    Map<String,String> result=exp.generatecode(Map.of("code",code,"exit",exit));
                    exit=result.get("exit");
                    if(!operand1.contains(result.get("code")))
                    operand1+= result.get("code");
                }
                if(exp.getProperty("operand").equals("operand2")) {
                    Map<String,String> result=exp.generatecode(Map.of("code",code,"exit",exit));
                    exit=result.get("exit");
                    if(!operand2.contains(result.get("code")))
                    operand2+= result.get("code");
                }
            }
    }
    code += operand1+operator+operand2; 
    if(!exit.equals("1"))
        code="";
    return Map.of("code",code,"exit",exit);
}
```

Main class contains

```
    Class1 aw_plus_w = new Class1();
    Class3 waw_plus = new Class3("+");
    aw_plus_w.addClass2(aw, Map.of("operand", "operand2"));
    aw_plus_w.addClass2(w, Map.of("operand", "operand1"));
    aw_plus_w.addOperator(waw_plus);
    Class1 c_minus_w = new Class1();
    Class3 cw_minus = new Class3("-");
    c_minus_w.addClass2(c, Map.of("operand", "operand2"));
    c_minus_w.addClass1(aw_plus_w, Map.of("operand", "operand1"));
    c_minus_w.addOperator(cw_minus);
    Class1 fr_div_size = new Class1();
    Class3 fr_div = new Class3("/");
    fr_div_size.addClass1(c_minus_w, Map.of("operand", "operand1"));
    fr_div_size.addClass2(size, Map.of("operand", "operand2"));
    fr_div_size.addOperator(fr_div);
    String code="";
    fr_div_size.generatecode(Map.of("code",code,"exit","0");
```

Expected result: ((aw+w)-c)/size
 but 
Actual result: ((w+aw-c-c)/(size()/(size)))

I tried for three days and could not find a way out. What is going wrong here? It will be grateful if anyone could point out the mistake

The updated sample code:

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

public class MyClass {
    abstract class Node
{
    public abstract String getCode();
//    public abstract boolean isAttribute();
}

public class Attribute extends Node
{
    private String name;
    public Attribute(String name)
    {
        this.name=name;
    }

    public String getCode()
    {
        return name;
    }

}

public class Expression extends Node
{
    private String name;
    private Set<Attribute> arg1 = new HashSet<Attribute>();
    private Set<Expression> arg2 = new HashSet<Expression>();
    private String op;
    public Expression(Set<Attribute> arg1,Set<Expression> arg2, String op)
    {
        this.arg1=arg1;
        this.arg2=arg2;
        this.op=" "+op+" ";
    }

    public String getCode()
    {
        String result="";
        // The correct code need to be written here
        return result;
    }

    public Expression(String name)
    {
        this.name=name;
    }

}
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        MyClass cl=new MyClass();
        cl.run();
    }

    public void run(){

        Attribute x=new Attribute("x");
        Expression xpx=new Expression(Set.of(x,x),null,"+");
        Expression xpxdx=new Expression(Set.of(x),Set.of(xpx),"/");
        System.out.println(xpxdx.getCode());
    }
}
```

Comment: Your curly braces are unbalanced, this will not compile.

Comment: Please check now

Comment: Where is the code that writes the parathesis?

Comment: You realize that Set.of(x,x) will only have a single element?

Comment: That's fine. We can assume (x,y) or any number of elements we want. But trying to write a generic code.

Answer (score 0):

I have not quite found the reason that you get the behaivor you are getting.  I suspect it arises in the code you are not showing.  (For example nothing in your code produces the "(" and ")" characters).

There is a likely bug though, in that at the top level you set exit="1", and you then pass that all the way down.

Your use of map to pass parameters makes your code much harder to read than it needs to be.

You should also look at polymorphism to carry the load for you.

If I understand your problem correctly the following is a simple implementation;
(Nesting of classes is because the online fiddle I was using did not allow multiple files, proper implementation should have separate classes in separate files.)

```
public class MyClass {
    abstract class Expression
{
    public abstract String getCode();
    public abstract boolean isLiteral();
}

public class Literal extends Expression
{
    private String name;
    public Literal(String name)
    {
        this.name=name;
    }

    public String getCode()
    {
        return name;
    }

    public boolean isLiteral()
    {
        return true;
    }
}
public class Binary extends Expression
{
    private Expression arg1;
    private Expression arg2;
    private String op;
    public Binary(Expression arg1,Expression arg2, String op)
    {
        this.arg1=arg1;
        this.arg2=arg2;
        this.op=" "+op+" ";
    }

    public String getCode()
    {
        String result="";
        if(!arg1.isLiteral()) result+="("+arg1.getCode()+")";
        else result+=arg1.getCode();
        result+=op;
        if(!arg2.isLiteral()) result+="("+arg2.getCode()+")";
        else result+=arg2.getCode();
        return result;
    }

    public boolean isLiteral()
    {
        return false;
    }
}

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        MyClass cl=new MyClass();
        cl.run();
    }

    public void run(){

        Literal x=new Literal("x");
        Expression xpx=new Binary(x,x,"+");
        Expression xpxdx=new Binary(xpx,x,"/");

        System.out.println(xpxdx.getCode());
    }
}
```

This can be further improved by having an enumeration for the allowed operators.

Also it really should use the StringBuilder class rather than direct string concatenation.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I could not portray it in the exact scenario. Now with the example, you have provided my code looks something like the updated code. Is this scenario understandable?

Comment: The reason it could not be straight forward as in plain java project is that it is a graph database POJO. Expression, Attribute and Node graph database entities. Hence the complication. The Expression will contain set of attributes and set of expressions separately and not together. It can contain any number of expressions, any number of attributes..

Comment: Do the method that reads from the database use the constructor?